# Inconsistent reputation totals

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

There is a 10 point (1 upvote) discrepancy between the dialog box that is shown when I mouseover my name and the reputation page in my profile. I've never seen it before today. I did wait about half an hour to see if it was a caching issue but it doesn't appear to be. I also logged out and back in with no change.

Screenshot below to illustrate what I see.

[image]

**update**

The counts were off by 10 until the end of the day. Then when rep for the day was reset to zero it seemed to clear up as the count for today is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rep today on the dropdown is the *total **change** today*, not reputation *earned* today.

*Example:*
When someone removes an upvote on an edited answer for example, you'll lose 10 rep.  This changes your *delta* for today (the popup), but not the *total earned* today (what's shown in the profile).

*Another example, which seems to be the case here:*
When a *user* is deleted their votes are as well, also affecting your delta but not the total for the day, so in these cases the numbers will be off a little.

You can recalc your rep at any time to sync these up at the bottom of your reputation history, available at: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/reputation

Comment: I just "lost" 41 points. I guess four people changed their minds when voting and one for good luck? :)

Comment: @John - sorry, it will go up and down as bad accounts are deleted

Comment: I think I'll live :)

Answer (score 1):

There's a similar discrepancy between the [leaderboards](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/9/alltime/webmasters) and the live rep. I always assumed it was a caching decision too and have been happy to live with it; the leaderboards seem to update every few hours (not that I check them obsessively, honest!). Perhaps the same is true of the profile popup.

You can trigger a reputation recount by hitting the button at the bottom of this page: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/reputation It doesn't seem to affect the cached scores, though, at least for me.

[image: reputation discrepancy]